# Setting a String Tag for a fragment

Tags: java, android

What is wrong with this code snippet ....  my app crashes here

```
frag.settext("Default Messaage");  // dEBUGGER SAYS THE PROBLEM IS HERE  IT THROWS NPE
```

Code Snippet

```
public void  question_displayer(View v){


    Log.i("create","question_displayer()");
    RamadanData data_object = new RamadanData();


   fragment_question_displayer at = new fragment_question_displayer(); 
    FragmentTransaction fragment_question = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(at, "why");
    fragment_question.replace(R.id.framelayout1, new fragment_question_displayer()  ,null);
    fragment_question.addToBackStack(null);
    fragment_question.commit();



   fragment_question_displayer  frag = (fragment_question_displayer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("why");
   frag.settext("Default Messaage"); // dEBUGGER SAYS THE PROBLEM IS HERE  IT THROWS NPE
```

**fragment_question_displayer    CLASS**

```
package com.alisaeed.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.alisaeed.newramadan.R;

public class fragment_question_displayer extends Fragment {
   Context context;
   TextView question_displayer;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        context = inflater.getContext();
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_displayer, container, false);
    //  TextView question_displayer = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView_question );
    //  question_displayer.setText("Default Message");
        return v;   
    }

 public void settext(String question){

          question_displayer = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.textView_question);
        question_displayer.setText(question);

     }


}
```

**question_displayer XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Question_displayer"
    android:tag="Hello"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:text="D" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="C" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="B" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated ... ........... Iam beginner at this android programming

**SCOTT**

```
public void  question_displayer(View v){


Log.i("create","question_displayer()");
    RamadanData data_object = new RamadanData();


   fragment_question_displayer at = new fragment_question_displayer(); 
    FragmentTransaction fragment_question = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,at, "why");
    fragment_question.replace(R.id.framelayout1, new fragment_question_displayer()  ,null);
    fragment_question.addToBackStack(null);
    fragment_question.commit();
   getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
   fragment_question_displayer  frag = (fragment_question_displayer)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("why");


   if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonnext)
   {
        String q = data_object.question_output(flag_autoquestion,"child","prayer" );
        frag.settext(q); 


     }


    switch(v.getId()){
    case (R.id.buttonPrayer):
    {


        Log.i("create","prayer()");

        if(child_selected == true && adult_selected==false && teen_selected==false )
        {
            Log.i("create","child_selected");

           String question= data_object.question_output(flag_autoquestion, "child","prayer");      
           Log.i("create",question);
           frag.settext(question);


           flag_autoquestion++;
                                   } 
           break;} 
                    }
                         }
```

Comment: Don't guess where the problem is, look at the stack trace from the crash. Also, your naming conventions are very, very non-java. Class names should be Pascal Case (`FragmentQuestionDisplayer`); methods should be Camel Case (`questionDisplayer()`).

Comment: sorry abt that will keep that in mind .... I ve written a similar code but with findFragmentbyId(int) method and it works fine but i want to know what is wrong with this ..  Can u tell me the concept regarding the first argument of the add function above i Knw its Fragment fragment but what is it

Comment: frag.settext("Default Messaage");  // dEBUGGER SAYS THE PROBLEM IS HERE  IT THROWS NPE

Comment: The only way that line can throw an NPE is if `frag` is `null`. You should check the line that initializes `frag` and figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Second Try...

If all else fails maybe try calling
`getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()`
before you call

`fragment_question_displayer frag =  (fragment_question_displayer)getSupportFragmentManager()  .findFragmentByTag("why");`

Fragment Transactions are threaded off and, thus, are at the mercy of the scheduler. If you need the transaction to happen immediately you can call the method mentioned above.

Comment: how can i get my view group id

Comment: @Taimoor go to this link of the android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html it shows the method `executePendingTransactions()` for type `FragmentManager`. `FragmentManager` is what gets returned by `getSupportFragmentManager()`. So yes, the method does exist

Comment: There was a mistake in the code of my answer, it should work now, sorry

Comment: it worked .. Thank you so much .. The problem know I face is when I press the button to go to the next question it overwrites the previous text... may be because  a new fragment is loaded ... Any idea How should i deal with ... may b with popBackStack  or something like that

Comment: Yea, I'd say a new fragment is the reason. Id have to see more code to be able to help further...